# Sending data over ADB

Tags: android, adb

Basically, I want to send an Android Device's serial number over ADB. I also want to be able to receive that data packet and parse it.

I'm wondering if there is a way that I can send JSONs between a computer and phone over ADB.

Comment: No. Adb is the **A**ndroid **D**ebug **B**ridge. It's used for debugging apps only. You can't make use of it in your app.

Comment: You can send files to/from an Android device via ADB, check the official guide: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#copyfiles

Answer (score 5):

You can use the activity manager (am). See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#am

For example you can send a string to your activity with:

```
 adb shell "am start -n com.package/com.package.MainActivity -e myKey 'stringvalue'"
```

And recover it from your activity with:

```
 getIntent().getStringExtra("myKey")
```

Note that if the activity is running, android will call onNewIntent with the intent as parameter.

Comment: Great answer. But I'm not able to send more than one word. How to send more than a word or preferably a few lines? I know I can try sending a file, but I don't want to do that. I want to send a few lines. Please help?

Comment: @MayankMohanUpadhyay You can use multiple words if you wrap them with quotes. I've added quote marks to the answer code. It accepts multiple lines. If you have special characters, you can first code the value with base64, and decode it later when received in java.

Comment: Hey, great answer. Is there a way to send information from the app to the adb machine?

Comment: @Mooncrater Not directly with this command. It will not wait for any result. Maybe you could write the result to logcat, and process it from adb machine. Or write the result to a file. If you submit a new Question with this issue, you will probably get better suggestions.